# PyQt - message change in text label in

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a CAN bus text label with PyQt
the text label name is 'label_5'
I was able to put a CAN bus message in label_5 one time but the message doesn't change in the window. the message stays the same even though this CAN bus message is constantly changing in the background. below is my code.

Can you please help me how I can display the constantly changing CAN bus message in the window?
Thank you in advance guys.

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication
from newcanmonitor import *

# Import UI File
from interface_ui import *


    #CAN bus message read from nacanmonitor.py
bus = can.interface.Bus('vcan0', bustype='socketcan_native')    
canbusmsg=read_bus('vcan0') #<-----CAN bus message


# MAIN WINDOW CLASS
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        # Setup the UI main window
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Show window
        self.show()

        # Customize
        self.ui.label_5.setText(canbusmsg) #<---- CAN bus message in label_5
```

Comment: Do you just expect to update itself whenever the message changes?  It sounds like you might want start here.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thanks alexpdev. I made a function with QTtimer and call it back when the timer timesout(1000). and it seems working.